# Efficient file format for video-like data

Tags: c++, video, kinect, file-format

I'm working with Kinect sensor and I want to store and load the data it produces. Essentially it gives me two types of frames (color and depth) which I save to a binary file. As each frame is just over 1Mb in size and Kinect records at 30 fps the files tend to grow pretty fast.

Now I need an efficient way to load the data and have a fast random access to the frames.

The way I've done it now is like this:

- I have a `Frame` class which contains of a frame header (frame number, timestamp, type, data size) and a pointer to the actual image data
- I have a `Replay` class which contains of a header (number of frames, resolution etc.) and two vectors: `frames` which contains `Frame` objects with data pointer initialized to NULL and `framePositions` which maps frame number to its location in the file.

  - When I need a frame I just load its data from the file.

The loading looks something like this (compacted):

```
Replay replay;
Frame frame;
int position = fStream.tellg();
fStream.read((char *) &frame.header, sizeof(frame.header));
fStream.ignore(frame.dataSize);    // skip image data for now
replay.insertFrame(frame, pos);    // put frame and pos into vectors
```

So this is better than loading everything into memory, but it's still slow. There's a MS software called Kinect Studio and it opens recorded files instantly. Literally in an instant, while my solution takes good few seconds to load a file of similar size. What kind of sorcery is this?

Now I've got a following idea: create an array of frames positions in the file, place it at the end of the file (since it will be variable size), put its offset and size in the header, don't even bother loading the frames, just load the array and request frames when needed.

I think it could work, but I decided to seek advice before trying to implement it, as I believe there are standard ways of dealing with such problems and I don't really want to reinvent the wheel through trial and error.

Comment: Perhaps the MS software is using mmap() (okay, the Windows equivalent of mmap()) to map the file into memory, so that it doesn't actually load in the data until the program tries to reference it?  That would make loading seem instantaneous (at the possible cost of slowing down playback unless they did some clever multithreading tricks to mask the slowdown)

Comment: Btw your idea sounds fine, I can't think of any reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try implementing it and see how it goes.